# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

After updating my flutter project when I was going to run the application in the android studio, I got the following error.

```
e: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-7.1.5\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (16, 16): Redeclaration: MethodCallHandlerImpl
e: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-7.1.6\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (17, 16): Redeclaration: MethodCallHandlerImpl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried following steps but I was not able to fix this.

- pub get, pub upgrade
- And here's my flutter doctor result

  "C:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" doctor --verbose
  [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804], locale en-US)
  • Flutter version 1.22.4 at C:\Program Files\flutter
  • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 months ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
  • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
  • Dart version 2.10.4

  [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
  • Android SDK at C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
  • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
  • ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
  • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
  X Android license status unknown.
  Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

  [!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
  • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
  X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
  X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

  [!] VS Code (version 1.53.0)
  • VS Code at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
  X Flutter extension not installed; install from
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

  [√] Connected device (1 available)
  • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

  ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
  Process finished with exit code 0

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was happened due to a pub cache conflict. The problem was fixed after executing the following command in the terminal.

1. dart pub cache repair
2. dart pub get
3. dart pub upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution but it does not work for me. My solution is update `compileSdkVersion` to `30` in my `app/build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the flutter toast version to latest fluttertoast version in dependencies in pubspec.yaml . It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error. Tried updating `compileSdkVersion`. Didn't work for me. This solved my problem.

1. pubspec.yaml -->> pub upgrade
2. Change `fluttertoast` version to latest
3. Pub get
4. Run...